# Allow user only 10 post per hour in Laravel app

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5

I have a site that allows a user to post a status similar to Facebook, I wan't to only allow the user to post up to ten post per hour, if the user tries to post over that amount in the same hour, I want to redirect the user with a message **Only 10 posts allowed an hour**.

My code to post status looks something like this:

```
public function postStatus(Request $request, LaravelFacebookSdk $fb, $checked) 
{
    $checked = $checked;
    $twitterToken = Session::get('access_token');

    $token = Session::get('fb_user_access_token');

    if ($request->has('image_id')) {
        $preloaded = new \Cloudinary\PreloadedFile($_POST['image_id']);
        if (!$preloaded->is_valid()) {
          echo "Invalid upload signature";  //Add a route to page with sorry there was a problem uploading your image.      
        } else {
        //Save Photo URL and User ID to Photo model
        $photorequest = $preloaded->pmsFileName();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $photo = new Photo;
        $photo->image_identifier = $photorequest;
        $photo->user()->associate($user);
        $photo->save();

        $regPhoto = Photo::select('id')->where('image_identifier', $preloaded->pmsFileName())->first();
        $statusPhotoID = $regPhoto->id;
    }


    }else{
        $statusPhotoID = NULL;
    }


    $this->validate($request, [
        'player_url' => 'url|max:255',
        'body' => 'max:1000',
    ]);

    if ($request->has('player_url') || $request->has('body') || $request->has('image_id')) {

        Auth::user()->statuses()->create([
        'body' => $request->input('body'),
        'player_url' => $request->input('player_url'),
        'status_photo_id' => $statusPhotoID,
    ]);

    $userPage = ' http://example.com'; //Do something like {{ route('profile.index', [username = Auth::user()->username])}}
    $tweetLength = 140 - strlen($userPage);

        //Post to Facebook with Image
        if ($checked == 'checked' && isset($photorequest)) {
            try
            {
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
                $fb->post('/me/photos', ['url' => cloudinary_url("$photorequest"),'caption' => $request->input('body') . $userPage]);
            }
            catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
            {
                // continue to next request;
            }
            //Post to Fb without Image
        } elseif ($checked == 'checked' && !isset($photorequest)) {
            try
            {
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
                $fb->post('/me/feed', ['message' => $request->input('body') . $userPage]);
            }
            catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
            {
                // continue to next request;
            }
        }
        //Post to Twitter with Image
        if($twitterToken && isset($photorequest)) {

            try
            {
                // Twitter::postTweet(['status' => str_limit($request->input('body') . ' SITE',137), 'format' => 'json']);
                $uploaded_media = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media' => file_get_contents(cloudinary_url("$photorequest"))]);
                Twitter::postTweet(['status' => str_limit($request->input('body') . $userPage,$tweetLength), 'media_ids' => $uploaded_media->media_id_string]);
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                // continue to next request;
            }
            //Post to twitter without image
        } elseif ($twitterToken && !isset($photorequest)) {
            Twitter::postTweet(['status' => str_limit($request->input('body') . $userPage,$tweetLength), 'format' => 'json']);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Status Posted.');
    }
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Error Occured, Nothing Posted.');

}
```

My table looks like:

`| id | user_id | parent_id | body | created_at | updated_at |`

In my `created_at` I'm using timestamp()

What's my best option to implement what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the current timestamp and deduct one hour worth of seconds. Then you can fetch the number of rows by adding a where clause like this (pseudocode of course)

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE created_at >= $timestamp`

All you then have to do is checking if the number of posts created in the last hour is less then ten.

Comment: could you explain a bit more please, like how to deduct hour worth of seconds?

Comment: You take time() and deduct 60*60 (3600) seconds from it. With the resulting value you run your query for counting the rows.

Comment: so something like:  
$timestamp = time() - 36000
$latestStatuses = Status::where('created_at', '>', $timestamp)->orWhere('created_at', '=', $timestamp)->get();
if ($latestStatuses->count() <= 10) {
 //allow user to post
}

Comment: I meant: so something like:  
$timestamp = time() - 36000
$latestStatuses = Status::where('user_id', 'auth::user()->id')->where('created_at', '>', $timestamp)->orWhere('created_at', '=', $timestamp)->get();
if ($latestStatuses->count() <= 10) {
 //allow user to post
}

Comment: Anyone who uses this make sure to format your time date like so : $time = time() - 36000;
  $timestamp = date("Y-m-d Y H:i:s",$time);